# Is it possible to prove that aggregating N relational database models will retain a relational model?

Tags: sql, database, relational-database

My question is given N relational databases in BCNF (or whatever normalization you desire) and Y aggregation services.  Is it always possible that my aggregation services can retain the relational model when consuming from my relational databases?  For example, I have two Oracle databases that store similar, but distinct data points for my aggregation service that will "enhance" the overall data and generate "true" answer for the current state of all known data.

Oracle A:

```
Table Cats  
age    sex  
12      F
10      M  
 8      F
```

Oracle B:

```
Table Cats  
sex    percentage  
F       66
M       34
```

Cat Aggregator:

```
age   sex  percentage  
12     F     33
10     M     33  
8      F     33
```

Let me know if I can provide more information

**Update one**

> It would appear that the content of "Oracle B" is completely redundant
>   here

For a more real world feeling, imagine I have an application that stores Cat data and you have an application that stores Cat data. Now a third party wants to query both of our applications and make their own Cat aggregator. Is it possible to prove that the aggregation of our two applications would yield a data set that is relational.

**Update Two**

I see some unclear closing votes.  I believe another way to ask this is as follows:

```
Let A = {'Cat','14','F'}  //animal,age,gender
Let B = {'Cat','14','33.33'} //animal, age, percent of population
Let C = A+B
```

If I add an arbitrary column to either A or B is it true that I can restructure C into a series of tables that allow for normalization to be retained?

Comment: It would appear that the content of "Oracle B" is completely redundant here...

Comment: @OliCharlesworth let Oracle B be a separate data system.  For a more real world feeling, imagine I have an application that stores Cat data and you have an application that stores Cat data.  Now a third party wants to query both of our applications and make their own Cat aggregator.  The crux is I don't know what data you have and you don't know what I have.

Comment: Also, isn't it the case that a normal form is a characteristic of a *table*, not of a *database*?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Yes it is a characteristic of a table, what would you call a database consisting of only normalized tables though?  Would you not call that a xth normal form database?  Just asking for my future knowledge.  However, my question still stands

Comment: Perhaps (I'm definitely not a DB expert, so not going to commit to an answer on that..).  But regardless of what you might call it, it is clearly the case that the overall combination of tables suffers from the possibility of inconsistency and redundancy.  Both of which sound like more practical problems than what you might call it ;)